# how can i write "%" in java printf method

Tags: java, printf

i want to know that how can i write "%", in java printf() method.

for example : `System.out.printf("it has %.4f%", a);`
hoped output : it had `33.3333%`

but, it had `UnknownFormatConversionException` Error.

so, how can i change that?

Answer (score 2):

The `%` sign should be escaped with a `%`. For example:

```
System.out.printf("it has %%%.4f%%", a);
```

will print: `it has %33.3333%`, for `a = 33.33333f;`

Answer (score 1):

Escape it !
`System.out.printf("%%")`